# UITextView content size not updating with font size change

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextview, contentsize

I have this function here, which is called after every time the text in my **quoteTextView** changes:

```
func sizeFontToFit(){

    quoteTextView.font = UIFont(name: quoteTextView.font.fontName, size: 20.0)

    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    println("Attempting to fit \(quoteTextView.text)")
    println()
    println("textView frame is w: \(quoteTextView.frame.size.width)  h: \(quoteTextView.frame.size.height)")
    println("contentSize    is w: \(quoteTextView.contentSize.width)  h: \(quoteTextView.contentSize.height)")
    println()

    while ((quoteTextView.contentSize.height < quoteTextView.frame.size.height) && (quoteTextView.font.pointSize < 100)){

        quoteTextView.font = UIFont(name: quoteTextView.font.fontName, size: quoteTextView.font.pointSize + 1)

        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        println("font size is \(quoteTextView.font.pointSize)")
        println("contentSize is w: \(quoteTextView.contentSize.width)  h: \(quoteTextView.contentSize.height)")

    }

    println("Done resizing")
}
```

**What it's supposed to do:**

I want the text in **quoteTextView** to always cover the entire screen, by changing its font size to fit. The function starts at the minimum size of 20, and if that doesn't cover it, then it should gradually increase the font size until it does (or hits the maximum size of 100).

**My problem is:**

The program recognises if the initial text is indeed too small or not. If there is enough text to cover the screen, it leaves it alone, as it should do; but if not then it starts doing the gradual changes to font size. The issue is that **quoteTextView.contentSize** doesn't update after each of those changes (the println's keep showing the initial value all theway through) and if there wasn't a limit of 100 font size, it would just go on an infinite loop.

So in the end I am left with all or nothing. The text size is always either at the minimum 20 or all the way at 100.

Is there a way to force contentSize to update? And if not, is there another way of doing this?

**EDIT:** 
replaced

```
quoteTextView.layoutSubviews()
```

with

```
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

where self is the viewController holding the textView
(no difference)

**FIXED:**

The problem was, as Rory said in the comments, that the texView had editable property turned OFF. Turning it on fixed it for me.

Comment: You don't call `-layoutSubviews` directly. Ever.

Comment: Try using `-sizeThatFits:` instead of forcing layout.

Comment: I don't understand what that function does very well. What should I use as a parameter? it asks for CGSize.

Comment: Try calling `setNeedsLayout` then `layoutIfNeeded` on the affected views.

Comment: @Rory McKinnel, same story

Comment: @Xebeq try doing the `layoutIfNeeded` calls on the main view or the containter view which holds the text view(s) and remove the `layoutSubviews` calls as you should not really call them which might be what is confusing things. `layoutSubviews` should get called by the layout mechanism when triggered. Sometimes calling `setNeedsDisplay` as well as `setNeedsLayout` also helps.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel See edit. Also tried `quoteTextView.layoutIfNeeded` and `quoteTextView.superview.layoutIfNeeded`. Same story.

Comment: Other posts mention checking `editable` is ON when changing the font. Also having `selectable` set to ON before you change the font.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Didn't cross my mind that `editable` OFF could be the problem. This was it indeed. Thanks for taking the time to help me.